# Is it possible to set a GRUB password in an Ubuntu VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have set up a GRUB password as per the link below:
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-password-protect-the-grub-boot-loader-in-ubuntu

I'm using a console to connect to the VM. I arrived at the GRUB start screen but I'm not able to type anything. The console looks frozen as per the attached image.

[image: Grub Start Screen]

Is it possible to set a Grub password and how can it be done?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the error in my own project.

[image]

And I investigated further trying to fix this issue. But unfortunately, **currently it is not possible** to set up the GRUB password in a VM Instance in GCP.

You could see that there is an opened Feature Request in Public Issue Tracker that requests it: [[FR] Enable option to set up "grub password" on GCE Instances.](https://issuetracker.google.com/133410832)

If you “star” the request you will receive notifications for any important updates and keep track of its progress.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reproduce it and your complete answer.